# increasing function which diverges to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f(x)$ be satisfying the following :

1. $f(x)$ is positive increasing function on $(0,\infty)$
2. $f(x)\rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$

I wonder under proposition is true.

For this $f(x)$, $f(x)/f(e^x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$

If not, I want to add the condition 'analytic'. Despite many attempts, no great results were achieved. Thank you..

I have found the counter-example. But I don't know about added condition 'analytic'..

Comment: I think the [super-logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Super-logarithm) would be a counterexample, for we have $\text{slog}\,\mathrm e^x\sim\text{slog}\,x$.

Comment: Oh.. Awesome. Thank you very much.